# Angular application to support both http and https

Tags: javascript, angular

I built an application for demo purposes that uses an Angular front-end hosted on a web server (nginx). The nginx instance, in addition to serving the compiled JS code, also acts as a reverse proxy for an application server that the browser needs to connects to. The flow is such that when I deploy this nginx on an infrastructure with any IP/FQDN, I can connect to this IP/FQDN and subsequent calls to the application server happens against the same IP/FQDN. You can see the architecture and the flow in [this](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/images/yelb-architecture.png) diagram.

The way it works is that the JS code contains an endpoint that I configure in the `environment.ts` file which contains this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  envName: 'prod',
  appserver_env: 'http://' + window.location.host
};
```

Every time the code needs to connect to the app server it uses the `appserver_env` variable that resolves to the same IP/FQDN it pulled the JS code from.

This works just fine if I deploy my application without any security (i.e. http). It doesn't work if my webserver only works with https. I can obviously change the `environment.ts` to specify https instead and that would work (in a secured environment) after recompiling the Angular code.

However, I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way to tell Angular that this configuration needs to be working with EITHER http or https depending on the deployment method I am using. This is a demo application that I want to use in the most flexible way.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you modify this setting at run time based on current protocol?

Comment: Tks. My primary use case is to deploy this app in a container. One option is to read an env variable at container start-time and sed the value of `appserver_env` to use https if said env variable was set (e.g. `PROTOCOL=HTTPS`). The other alternative was to create two endpoints in `environment.ts` (one w/ http and one w/ https) and build logic in my JS code to "try one first and if it fails try the other". I can do either but I was hoping there was a "native/out-of-the-box" way to deal with this http/https switch w/ the library I am using (@angular/http). What were you thinking specifically?

Comment: I'm assuming that http/https protocol is the same for front end and api. I was thinking modifying the url at run time when the app loads (e.g. using APP_INITIALIZER token), based on the current url protocol. Otherwise, using `://url.com` should also work (I.e. not specifying protocol)

Comment: Thanks David. Yes the assumption is correct in that the protocol is the same. I have tried to set the endpoint variable in `environment.ts` from `appserver_env: 'http://' + window.location.host` to `appserver_env: '://' + window.location.host` but that won't work. The JS program complains it can't find the server. I will have to explore other venues. Thanks.

Comment: The initial value for `environment` object is set at compile time, so I'm not sure how it'd work with `window.location`. Did you debug to check the value of the `environment` object when you are running your app?

Comment: `windows.location.host` resolves (at run-time) the name of the site I am connecting to. So if I deploy my app behind the FQDN `myapp.myarbitrarysite.com` the flow is such that, when I connect to that site, the `appserver_env` variable gets populated with that name and that is the name I subsequently use to make calls to the app server. See [here](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/location/host/). If there was a way to explicitly capture the protocol in addition to the hostname+port that would solve my problem.

Comment: AH! There is apparently? https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/location/href/ (testing now)

Comment: Yep! with `href` it worked. That was exactly what I needed. For those visiting this thread, the window.location directive has a ton of options in fact beyond `host`. See here: https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/location/